# How can I backup Sharepoint online (sites & documents) and restore?

Tags: sharepoint-online, backup, restore

How can I backup Sharepoint online (sites & documents) and restore? Can this be achieved without using 3rd party tool?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box backup tools for SharePoint Online, just the recycle bins and retention / DLP.  There are third party tools out there to do this, some store the data in their cloud, others let you store the data anywhere you want.  It all depends on your requirements and data security needs.

Answer (score 0):

**There are the following SharePoint online backup options for reference：**

**Standard Microsoft 365 Recovery**

The standard versioning lets you keep up to **50,000** last versions of most SharePoint items and the post-deletion retention helps you recover data within **93** days after it was deleted.

[image]

**Compliance Retention(avilable in E3+ plans)**

The compliance retention capabilities are included in premium Microsoft 365 subscriptions. They are a powerful tool enabling administrators to capture & backup almost all versions of SharePoint data.

The primary purpose of the compliance retention is archiving and e-discovery for litigation & compliance purposes. The compliance retention policies enable admins to search & export the data offline, but have no automated data recovery capabilities back to Microsoft 365 (because those are not required in archiving & e-discovery).

Therefore, **the main limitation of this tool is the absence of automated recovery options**. To recover lost data administrators need to download it offline, and then manually upload it back to SharePoint online.

**Third-party Backups**

**Veeam** and **Afi** provides one of the most complete SharePoint backup options compared to other players. The products enable backup and restore of web pages (most other solutions can backup these data types, but cannot restore them correctly back to SharePoint). The two tools also support Classic site pages and site mailboxes.

[image]

More information, please refer to **[this article](https://afi.ai/blog/sharepoint-online-backup)**.